# getting error when tried to push files/folder to github

Tags: git, github, push, addition, commit

[image]
issue in by git bash:

```
firoz@DESKTOP-B1HH3RG MINGW64 ~/gitproject/git-demo (master)
$ git add .
error: 'websites/' does not have a commit checked out
fatal: adding files failed
```

Please help me out how to fix this issue. I have created locally a website which is having .git file by default under my git-demo folder. When I tried to commit so that it pushed to my github repo, it shows the error above. 
[See here](https://github.com/firoz786/git-demo)

Comment: this was an operator error issue. you figured that out... great! But now delete this question rather than answering it as it doesn't help anyone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

i just found the fix. 
Actually the folder which i want to commit is having .git file which is restricting git commit . command . So i just deleted .git file and then the command run without error . Please see the image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOf6g.png) for better understanding .